# How many AES-operations have to be watched for key-exploit by side-channel attacks?

Tags: aes, side-channel-attack

If I would like to exploit a used key by side-channel attack, one that measures electromagnetic fields, how many runs of the AES-128 do I need to spy on for a successful exploit?

I can't use any programs or software on that device. AES is software implemented. And I try (theoretically!) to spy in a distance of X meters. I am able to reduce the noise by surrounding emissions. But I can't have any type of access. So the attack model specifies using a sniffer.

I do not need an exact number of traces. There are only certain values for trace/distance that I could think of. I just found the TEMPEST attack, which needs 400k traces in a distance of 0.3 meters and 2.3m in 1 meter.

Comment: Any such value would be extremely dependent on the device being attacked; not only the AES implementation (e.g. are we talking about AES-NI, or the standard table-based implementation), but in addition to the physical details of the device.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [poncho](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/452/poncho), it is not possible to precisely answer your question since too many parameters are involved:

- About the AES implementation: is it an unsecured implementation? Does it use masking? If yes, at which order? And so on...
- The physical properties of the device also matter, does it leak a lot? Are there some hardware countermeasures such as a shield, a jitter, etc...
- What equipment is used to measure leakages? Depending on the probe, the oscilloscope and its setup, the number of AES executions to achieve a 100% success rate may vary greatly.

To put it in a nutshell, you have to make practical experiments to answer your question.

Comment: Lets say it is an standard implementation of AES-GCM, released by any control instance like IEEE or ISO/NIST and so on. If I could sniff into 900 AES-Runs, is there a way to compromise the key?

Comment: @Shalec Maybe, it depends on the other parameters.

Comment: Hm.. to get a decision about side-channel security on a software implementation, it seems  to depend allways on the special case. If I could sniff 1k AES-Operations, is there any way or worst-case Implementation, where I could exploit the used key? Furthermore, if I know a Plain/Ciphertext pair, which is used 4-times in a row (Dec, Enc, Dec, Enc) and produces 1k AES-Operation (because of block-length of the input), is there any benefit? I just need to figure out, if it is realistic, that someone could succesfully attack such a system without physical contact.

Comment: could you recommend me a book for studying this in the deep? As I figured out, I can't imagine how to think about side channel attacks.

Comment: Lets say we consider the weakest known hardware surrounding and the best known software implementation of AES. (In case of security) Is there something, we could use it as a reference, to say: Every improvement on hardware-hardness will be more save, than this, in case of side-channel? I'm just interested in the minimum of sniffed AES-uses.